# How to convert Array{Float64, 1} to float in julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

Someone knows how to convert an array{Float64,1} to a Float64?

When I do:

```
M=rand(5,5)
a=M[:,1]' * M[:,1]
if a<0
    print("Less than 0")
else
    print("more")
end
```

I have an error: " isless has no method matching isless(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Int 32) in < at operators.jl:32

Can anyone tell me please how to convert the `array{Float64,1}` a to a `float64` or tell me how to compare a 1 element array a to a float?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This operation really only makes sense when you are certain that your `Array{Float64, 1}` has a single element. In this case you can access it as `a[1]`.

For your example I'd recommend using the `dot` function (`a = dot(M[:,1], M[:, 1])`) or the `norm` function (`a = norm(M[:, 1])^2`)